# output is blank in master layout using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, layout, laravel-blade, master-pages

I am new to Laravel,i am using template layout inheritance for laravel blade,here is my code, it is just simple to show hello on browser. but after running this, my output is display blank. there is no error shown on browser or console window. please help me to find my mistake.

**master.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>master page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    @yield('content')
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**body.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
<h1> Hello </h1>
@endsection
```

**studentcontroller.php**

```
public function viewmasterpage()
{
    return view('master');
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/masterpage','studentcontroller@viewmasterpage')->name('masterpage');
```

Answer (score 1):

you are returning the `master` layout in `studentcontroller` there for you will find nothing you need to return `body` which extends `master` layout and contains `<h1> Hello </h1>`

```
public function viewmasterpage()
{
    return view('body');
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but why did not it work with page link?

Comment: if i got your question right the `master` page will show nothing because it's empty it's only a layout for other pages

Comment: Yes exactly, this is what i am asking, why did not we used master page link in controller?

Comment: Ok. master pages or master layouts tend to be used as template a layout of your other pages for example you have a `login` and `register` pages and they are have the same html and css except the the form it self for this scenario you create a master layout for authentication pages `auth-layout` and both pages will extend it, so what will you return to view `login` and `register` pages or the `auth-layout` which doesn't have any form, of course you will return `login` and `register`